# invalid url when downloading jpg image to android

Tags: android, asynchronous, bitmap, download

I am getting a nullPointerException when trying to download a jpg file.  It is done in an AsyncTask method and I can't trace the program flow in the debugger probably because it is
asynchronous. My trace reveals that 2 records were read before it stopped. I am using port 8000 as my local server and the url it stops on is

```
      http://10.0.2.2:8000/my_album/5_irises.jpg".
```

Is there something special about downloading jpegs versus png files or is my url coded incorrectly?  Is the underscore a problem in the url?  Also, do I have to close the connection after each download?

```
 begin of loop {
  ........
   new AccessImages().execute(urlstring);
  }  ......end of loop 

 private class AccessImages extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urladds){
            return downloadImage(urladds[0]);
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bm) {
            bitmap_photo[itemcount] = bm;
            itemcount++;
        }
        }

  private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Log.d("downloadImage", url);
        Bitmap bmap = null;
        InputStream inStream = null;
    //  Drawable drawable = null;
        try {
            inStream = openHttpConnection(url);
            Log.d("inStream", String.valueOf(inStream));
        //  drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inStream, "src");
            Log.d("before bmap", url);
            bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);
            Log.d("after bmap", url);
            inStream.close();

        }
        catch (IOException el) {
            el.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmap;
    }

    private InputStream openHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {

        InputStream inStream = null;
        int checkConn = -1;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        try {

            Log.d("try openhttpconnection", urlString);
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            checkConn = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (checkConn == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                inStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                Log.d("instream", urlString);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return inStream;
    }
```

I just found out the NullPointerException was at this instruction:

```
   inStream.close();
```

What would cause that?

Ok.  Now I corrected for the inStream not being null but now I am getting NullPointerException from the following instruction:  bitmap_photo[itemcount] = bm;

```
  if(bm != null)
            {
            bitmap_photo[itemcount] = bm;
            itemcount++;
            }
```

Can't I check for a null value in a bitmap or is the array the problem?  I should add that I created the bitmap_photo array as follows:  Is this a problem?

```
          Bitmap [] bitmap_photo;
```

Comment: You can use 'Log' class to print your logs and find out where exactly are you getting null pointer exception?

Comment: I know it's not your answer you are looking for, but are you familiar with this library? https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader It's awesome!!

Comment: Yes, I am familar with this library and picked up some pointers.  I am trying to write my own routine as I want to be able to learn how to this stuff.  I am making the transition from C# to Java and find it really challenging.

Comment: With regards to what would cause inStream.close() to throw exception, in openHttpConnection(), inStream would not be set to appropriate value if your check for "if(checkConn == HTTP_OK)" returned false. You need to do a null check before calling "instream.close()".

Comment: Saw your edited question .. That is not the problem .. You should not be proceeding ahead if your image download was not successful ... since your 'checkConn==HTTP_OK' check is failing , that means your image wasn't downloaded successfully. Try to debug that. And the reason that you are getting a NULL pointer exception after that might be because you haven't initialized bitmap_photo. You have just declared it. Also, make sure that you have initialized 'itemcount' to 0.